# How to tell if /proc/[pid]/status has changed without opening the file

Tags: c, linux, file, file-io, proc

Is there a way to tell if the contents of the stat/status file for a process has changed, without opening it?

I was thinking you could just check the last-modified time, however the timestamp almost never changes. I coded this using stat(), however it did not return the desired effect (same with ls under the shell.)

It's quite possible I'm looking about this the wrong way. I'm just wanting to be able to constantly probe the stat values of the process, similar to the top command (and no, taking data from top is nowhere near acceptable.)

Comment: Opening, reading the pseudofile, and closing it does not take much time at all, because the contents are produced in-kernel as needed. However, parsing the data does take a relatively long time. What I'd do, is first calculate a quick hash (maybe [djb2 xor](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html) hash), and use the length and the hash to detect if changes have occurred, and only re-parse the data if either or both differ from the previous run. (You can use that hashing run to e.g. count the entries, too, or to compact the whitespace making parsing simpler.)

Comment: Very nice idea for optimization, thank you. This is rather important as I'm dealing with embedded devices, and I'm sure sscanf etc is very intensive comparatively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this using any normal I/O operations on stat/status because they're not true files.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90627/notify-of-changes-on-a-file-under-proc explains why you can't work with these files like with regular files.

Comment: Darn. Seemed like it would be the way -- looks like I might just open the file repetitively. Looks like the data is never actually stored inside as a file or in RAM; it's generated by the kernel when the 'file' is accessed.

Comment: Thanks @Saustin for the edit. I was in the rush and was not happy about the way it was phrased. You made it much clearer.